# cypress.js e2e test all elements are undefined

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli, cypress

I've been working on a huge sized app for a while, and just got started working on writing e2e test.

The app is Vue-cli 3.0 app, which had had the testing platform 'nightwatch' as default but later changed to 'cypress'. problem is, a simple login test works whereas anything larger than that crashes.

the very same app, passes the test with this code:

```
import { email, password } from '../../testinfo'

describe('login test', () => {
  it('login', () => {
    cy.visit('/')
    cy.contains('#btnLogin', 'Login')
    // cy.contains('#btnSignUp', 'Sign up')
    cy.get('#btnLogin').click()
    cy.get('#input-email > input').type(email)
    cy.get('#input-pw > input').type(password)
    cy.get('#btnProceedLogin').click()
    cy.wait(3000)
    cy.contains('a', 'Team')
    cy.contains('a', 'Tournament')
  })
})
```

but this code fails:

```
import { email, password } from '../../testinfo'
import nanoid from 'nanoid'

describe('team related stuff test', () => {
  it('team creation and delete', () => {
    cy.visit('/')
    cy.contains('#btnLogin', 'Login')
    cy.contains('#btnSignUp', 'Sign up')
    cy.get('#btnLogin').click()
    cy.get('#input-email > input').type(email)
    cy.get('#input-pw > input').type(password)
    cy.get('#btnProceedLogin').click()
    cy.wait(3000)
    cy.get('#navTeam').should('exist')
    cy.get('#navTeam').trigger('mousedown')
    cy.get('.make > button').click()
    cy.get('#full-form-name > input').type(`[test]${nanoid}`)
    cy.get('#full-form-select-game > div > div > button').click()
    const gameMax = cy.get('#full-form-select-game > div > ul').length
    const targetGameIdx = Math.floor(Math.random() * gameMax)
    cy.get('#full-form-select-game > div > ul')[targetGameIdx].click()
  })
})
```

what I cannot understand is that the second testing spec fails with a message `cannot read property click of undefined`. it doesn't matter if I put `cy.wait(3000)` to the front, or if I give it a delay.

Funny thing is, if I put `cy.wait()` to the front, it should wait 3 seconds at least before it shows the error message regarding interacting with an element, but as soon as I boot up the app, the error message pops up in an instant.

Comment: Can you remove some of the code that does not pertain to your issue, if that is possible? I am looking at your issue now.. Is it this code cy.get('#btnLogin').click() that is causing your problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your issue is here:

```
const gameMax = cy.get('#full-form-select-game > div > ul').length
```

You cannot store values like this. Your code runs all at once at the beginning of the test run before anything else happens. Each command simply tells Cypress to do something in the future. If you want to queue your own code to run in order with everything else, you can use `.then()`, like so:

```
// ...
cy.get(#full-form-select-game > div > ul').then(elements => {
    const gameMax = elements.length;
    const targetGameIdx = Math.floor(Math.random() * gameMax);
    cy.get('#full-form-select-game > div > ul')[targetGameIdx].click();
});
```

Replace the last three Cypress commands with this and it *should* work. I haven't tested it, but it should at least put you on the right track.

A basic understanding of how Cypress works is essential to writing Cypress tests. If you haven't already, I strongly suggest reading the fantastic [introduction to Cypress](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/introduction-to-cypress.html) in the docs.

Comment: Thank you. It does work as you said. The test on custom dropdown element still needs a fix though. The provided link to the article really helped me get the grasp of the cypress testing.

Comment: Just made an edit to the third line. Not sure how I missed it, but I should have replaced the `cy.get()`, which was the entire purpose of using a `.then()`.

Comment: If you're having an issue with a different part of the code, I suggest asking another question. It's typically best to ask about one specific issue at a time.

Comment: No you didn't miss anything. I noticed I had not been aware of indeterministic nature of Cypress. When I said it still needs some more fix, there was some sort of typo in the function which is quite trivial.